# How to use following API with WordPress?

Tags: api, wp-api

I have an old client who wants to integrate one system on their WordPress website.

The company is fairly new called LYFSIZE which basically takes the picture of the users and provides them the exact size measurements for the apparels.

I was successfully able to achieve the steps provided in this file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZN4TJasAkLNV-vbg0MZQN045tcA906l/view?usp=sharing

Now, LYFSIZE has sent me documentation on how to use their API on the WordPress site.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xxe7PVoJBW8PTU9FIfNLYhF2qItrX5p4/view?usp=sharing

I have never used API with the WordPress site and I am completely clueless on the procedure. I tried to follow the steps and was able to reach the final steps.

However, I am not understanding how to put this on the subdomain to actually test it on the WP site. How to initialize the API? How to use the SDK files on the WP site?

I have got SDK Files, Demo API keys.

I know this is like asking for training but it would be really nice if someone could guide me little or otherwise I don't know what I would say to the client.

Comment: Does sound like a very big task that maybe you should look for professional help with. If I were you I would try and use the API entirely outside of Wordpress first to understand how it works, and only then begin to integrate it into your Wordpress, but this is very broad advice without looking in depth at this case.

Comment: @mozboz Hello. Thank you for your thoughts. Even I feel like it's not pretty simple and asking for an entire tutorial is not appropriate.

Comment: It's far too large a topic to cover on this site. What skills do you have? Have you built WordPress plugins before but are just unsure about making API requests? Or are you completely out if your depth (nothing to be ashamed of)? If you're not a programmer yourself, you would just to tell the client that you would need to hire one to complete the task. It's perfectly normal for new requirements to require new work. But if you've misrepresented your abilities then there's not much anyone here can do to help.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for the reply. I have built WordPress sites using themes and plugins. I do have a good understanding of front end languages but very less with PHP. I agree with you, I think it's better to tell the client to give this task to someone who is more experienced in this.